# Sync adapter definition

Tags: android, definition, android-syncadapter

Although I have implemented sync adapters and I can describe what a sync adapter is, I wanted to find the definition of it. 
I did not find it.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) I found a description that is clear but it is not a definition.

Is there, somewhere, a formal definition of an Android SyncAdapter?
For example is it strictly necessary to extend [AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html)? It does not look like that to me but that page seems to assume it.

Best regards

Comment: Can u plz provide the solution for the following link:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326366/android-updating-contact-details-on-a-webserver-via-user-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only definition I have found in the Android documentation is something like: "sync adapters" [components] to connect to any backend"